# libvirt and kvm/qemu, password on console redirection/serial doesn't work

Tags: console, serial-port, serial-console, libvirt

I have added a serial,and a console to connect my vm without X using this command.

```
virsh console myvm
```

Unfortunately my vm has a luks encrypted root and..I can put the password only from graphical console.
I can see the output on virsh console but when I try to insert the password..it echoes the carachters and inserting nothing.
Why?

Here you can see console output..and echoing of my vda3 luks password

[image]

Guest and host are both slackware 14.2
I've also redoing mkinitrd and inserting the virtio-console module, nothing.